# Why isn't operator overloading available for classes in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, class, operator-overloading

I've always wondered about this for a bit, but why is operator overloading not available for classes in Delphi?

I remember reading an answer once while on the run, and it said it would come in conflict with something, but I can't remember much. As far as I can tell, only the implicit operator may cause a bit of problems since classes are stored on the heap and assigning is actually a copy of the heap address (basically copying pointers).

Comment: It works in Delphi.NET because .NET does garbage collection. This could be solved in the native Delphi in two ways: 1. if operators were allowed on interfaces, and the classes implementing those operator would inherit from TInterfacedObject. 2. if managed classes were added to the Delphi language. Right now, Mason is right: you'd get memory leaks all over the place. See also my talk referenced on this link: http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/delphi-operator-overloading-table-of-operators-names-and-some-notes-on-usage-and-glitches/

Comment: Yes, I see why this might be regarded as a problem, and this is exactly what I've read in that article, now that I remember it. However, as I said in my comment to Mason's answer, I don't think this is actually a limitation, as I think you can do it if you implement just a little garbage collection (which won't have any side-effects).

Comment: If intefaces would have operators, then a whole lot of problems would arise, like for example not being able to cancel out some operators. For example, imagine having an Implicit operator in an interface and then having an object that does need the interface but absolutely not the Implicit operator as well. When you try an assignment, all hell might break loose, and it'd be hard to find your problem.
Thing is, operators should never be inherited, if you want to use the "inherited" version you should overload it again and then typecast. But that means classes have to have it, too.

Comment: As for managed classes, aren't that what records kinda are? Granted, they don't have inheritance and all the other features which truly define OOP, but they could.

Comment: Yeah, you could implement operator overloads as an interface, but that leads to problems of its own. Once you take a TInterfacedObject and set its interface reference count to 1, it's no longer safe to treat it as a normal object, because it'll die as soon as the last interface reference to it disappears.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can I not use operator overloading for classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541928/why-can-i-not-use-operator-overloading-for-classes)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Close.  It's because objects are reference types and the memory is managed manually.  So if you said `myResult := myObject1 + myObject2 + myObject3;`, you'd have to create an intermediate object somewhere in there, and there's no code to free it, so you get memory leaks.

Comment: Compilers can add the code to manage strings, so why can't it handle the hidden object? I don't think this is the reason.

Comment: @mj2008: For one thing strings don't, and cannot, have custom constructors.  The intermediate objects in this case could well be invalid if not instantiated with an appropriate constructor with appropriate parameters that the compile may not always/ever be able to determine.  The limitations that would have to be imposed on classes to support operator overloading would I suspect outweigh the benefit.  And since you can now have "records with methods", you can use operator overloading in conjunction with those if you wish.

Comment: I see why at first glance it wouldn't work. However, couldn't the compiler automatically destroy the intermediary objects except for the last one in this case, and then treat the assignment as normal?
For example, first create myIntermediaryObject1 as the result of (myObject1 + myObject2), then add it with myObject3 creating myIntermediaryObject2, automatically destroying myIntermediaryObject1 and the doing the assignment as usual?
After all, it's the programmer's resposibility to care for de-allocating myResult if necessary, and the compiler can take care of the rest of the temporary objects.

Comment: The problem with "records with methods", btw, is that records don't have some OOP features like inheritance (which basically also cancels out polymorphism, virtual methods, and all other things that make us use classes instead, even when not necessary).

Comment: Btw, the Intermediary objects I'm talking about in this case would be constructed in the overloaded operator method, so no need for the compiler to know which constructor to call, just to know for what objects to call the destructor.
Also, myIntermediaryObject2 is the only one not getting destroyed, and it will be the new object myResult will point to, just like in a normal assignment (and the programmer should expect the pointer to the heap object to change like in a normal scenario as well, so I don't see a problem here with manual de-allocation).

Comment: The compiler can't destroy the intermediate objects for because the Delphi objects has no default destructors.

Comment: The reason the compiler can't destroy the intermediary objects is that it has no way of knowing whether there's any "intermediary" object at all. The operator might return an instance of some cached object from a previous long calculation, or it might return one of the operand objects, or it might return something that needs to keep on existing beyond the current expression, such as an object representing an AST that's going to be evaluated later in the program. The compiler has *no idea* where the object came from or what you'll use it for later.

Comment: Ok, that's clear enough for me. :D Thanks for all the details and having patience with me.

Comment: If it's an interfaced object, would the problem be solved (reference counting)? What's preventing us to be able to overload operators on classes that implement interfaces?

Answer (score 1):

You can have operator overloading for classes, but only for the NextGen compiler where classes use ARC.
See: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/class_operators_delphi.html

This was introduced in XE5, see: [List of Delphi language features and version in which they were introduced/deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460037/list-of-delphi-language-features-and-version-in-which-they-were-introduced-depre)

Answer (score 0):

Mason Wheeler says that it's impossible because intermediate object management.

But according to Embarcadero documentation, class operators where possible with Delphi 2009.

[RAD Studio 2009 - Operator Overloading](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/operatoroverloads_xml.html)
 [New Delphi language features since Delphi 7](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/34324)

Comment: Operator overloading are for records. Records are value types while classes are reference types. The documentation in your links are wrong (although they state that this feature is for records, but fail by using classes in examples). See [`XE3 Operator Overloading`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Operator_Overloading_(Delphi)).

Comment: It's only allowed in records, not classes. But now with XE the records can have methods and properties. So...

Comment: @All The docs are the way they are because the .net compiler supported op overloading over classes. Possible because of GC.